# FSL (tbss) randomise command makes none permutations

Tags: permutation, anova

I'm working on TBSS FSL to make an ANOVA with 3 groups and ~20 subjects per groups. In order to analyze my sample, I have to perform a randomise command which basically make permutations inside my sample.

The command is the following :

```
randomise -i all_FA_skeletonised -o tbss -m mean_FA_skeleton_mask -d design.mat -t design.con -f design.fts –e design.grp --T2
```

where the design.mat matrix is the matrix which attributes subjects inside the different group, the design.con is the matrix of contrast which computes  comparisons between the groups, whereas the .fts and .grp are the files needed to make the ANOVA and are given by the GLM interface inside fsl.

My problem is that fsl actually do none permutation...

```
Data loaded
1 permutations required for exhaustive test of f-test 1
Doing all 1 unique permutations
Starting permutation 1 (Unpermuted data)
Critical Value for: tbss_tfce_corrp_fstat1 is: 6.3312e+06
```

I just show you what I would expect when I was doing t-test without ANOVA, the command was the following :

```
randomise -i all_FA_skeletonised -o tbss -m mean_FA_skeleton_mask -d design.mat -t design.con -n 500 --T2
```

And the terminal answer was :

```
Data loaded
1.10355e+34 permutations required for exhaustive test of t-test 1
Doing 500 random permutations
Starting permutation 1 (Unpermuted data)
Starting permutation 2
Starting permutation 3
...
Starting permutation 500
Critical Value for: tbss_tfce_corrp_tstat1 is: 341255
```

It looks like if the program computed by itself the needed number of permutations and find 1. Though, I tried to force the number of permutations by adding the `-n 500` command for the ANOVA without success.

I am not confident enough with fsl(tbss) and so I don't understand what the programm does and why it doesn't make the permutations. Does anyone have any idea ? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you post the content of the design matrix and contrast file?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you need design.grp. To my understanding, -e design.grp option is only needed for Within/Mixed group design (like paired T-test, or repeated ANOVA). Please see here about Exchangeability Blocks: https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/PALM/ExchangeabilityBlocks